# tpl php variable removing http www

Tags: php, http, web, task-parallel-library

i have in a file with extension tpl this variable:

```
{$site.url}
```

this varable contain urls in this format `http://www.google.com/` with slash final

I want convert  urls in this format `google.com` without http.www and without slash final 
and create a new variable to insert in accetable format for tpl file 
How to

Comment: are you using a framework/template engine? like smarty maybe (considering it's  one of the systems that uses .tpl files)

Comment: Sorry, what? Do you have an array of urls, and you want to extract the domain from the URL? Or have I completely misunderstood?

Comment: yes is a file of a template of a directory

Comment: if you have an existing directory solution and it uses smarty (if I understood it right) and you want to make changes mostly to the template (not to affect the core) you can use variable modifiers (search smarty manual) and you will be able to call a function on some of the variables like this {$site.ur|somefunction} instead of {$site.url}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`replace`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl) modifier

```
{$site.URL|replace:'http://www.':''|replace:'/':''}
```

The above code will basically strip out the `http://www.` and all `/` part from the URL.
However, if the URL strings won't be always in `http://www.domain.tld/` format, it's probably better if you create a plugins for Smarty based on Jan-Henk's code as an example.

You can find the documentation for creating plugins [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

You must update the variable that contains your URL in the PHP code before assigning it to your templating engine. You should be able to do that with the following code:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$host = str_replace('www.', '', $host);
```

Then you can assign the $host variable to your template.